# IOS Export Compliance Info has Changed

Tags: ios, encryption, app-store-connect

Just before submitting my app, I realized that my export compliance info is incorrect. I used to get this warning where I always selected NO for test flight testing, but the correct answer should have been YES on the first question and on the second one that I am exempt because I only use https encryption.

Now I added `<key>ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption</key><false/>` to Info.plist, but I don't get the warning anymore. Before, I didn't "ALWAYS" get the warning. I think I only got it once in a while? I'm not sure if now I don't get the warning because I already added the nonExceptEncryption info to plist, if I'm supposed to update the encryption info elsewhere or if I should keep uploading builds until I get the warning again.

Comment: So, you're asking ... what?

Comment: How I can get back to that warning and change it to YES and then select excempt. The warning doesn't come up anymore, but apple says there are severe penalties if you publish with the wrong selection.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading a new build brings you the dialogue back. Each build "asks" this question.